# is it possible to make a div within header container full screen width?

Tags: html, css

I got a new design for an existing website our company made. It has navigation buttons within a container that is inside the header container.

in the new design this navigation bar has the full screen width.

is it possible to do this without changing the html code? (because they told me not to touch the html.)

I hope I made my question clear enough.

/edit .  I need to work only with the css code.

```
.header_div_button_container {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -131px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 130px;
}
.homepage .header_div_button_container {
    margin-left: -137px;
}
.header_div_button {
    background-color: #034ea2;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 16px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 110px;
}
```

this is a small part of the css i got. the html is mostly created by the cms we use and its not really readable for stackoverflow.

i hope you can do something with this.

Comment: Nope. Not clear enough!

Comment: And fiddle? for example what you try to reach.

Comment: You want to make a change to a HTML design whithout changing the HTML code? A CSS change?

Comment: the navigation bar currently is the 100% width of its container (of course). but the design has it the full screen width(body). but I am not really allowed to change the html. so is it possible to do this with css. (dont have a fiddle sorry)

Comment: Are you actually changing the width of the header / navigation or are you just wanting the background to extend to 100% of the viewport window.

Comment: If you show us the HTML and CSS it would be easier to help out.

Comment: @Paulie_D yes! thats exactly what i need actually. u got the code for that?

Comment: It depends on your HTML so I'd like to look at your code first.

Comment: We need the HTML code or even better just the CSS snippet that relates to what you want to change

Comment: @Paulie_D I indeed need the background of this navigation bar to be the full width of the screen(body). and the navigation buttons need to be within the container. where they are right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a structure like this

**HTML**

```
<header>

  <div class="inner"></div>

</header>
```

Your **CSS** can look like this:

```
.inner {
  height:100px;
  max-width:1100px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;

}
.inner:before, .inner:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightblue;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 9999px;   /* some huge width */
  z-index:-2;
} 

.inner:before {
  right: 100%; 
}
inner:after {
  left: 100%;

}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IzlKo)

Base article: [**http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/**](http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/)

Comment: thank you very much, I think ill be able to figure it out with the link you gave me ;)